# Is it possible to constrain generic types to Interface, new()?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, constructor, constraints

I'm trying to create a simple object recycling class

```
public class ObjectPool<T> where T : class, IRecyclable, new()
{
}
```

I want to be able to use it with my interface:

```
public interface ISomeInterface : IRecyclable
{
}

ObjectPool<ISomeInterface> pool = new ObjectPool<ISomeInterface>();
```

But this yields the error:

```
error CS0310: The type `ISomeInterface' must have a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter `T' in the generic type or method `ObjectPool<T>'
```

From what I have read online I know that I can't specify a constructor in an interface.

I have read that you can use reflection instead of "new" to create a new instance, though I'm concerned about the speed of performing this instantiation.

What is the correct way to resolve this situation? Is there a simpler solution that I'm completely overlooking?

Comment: you have to give it a concrete type if you use `class` and `new`

Comment: Even if you solve this problem, how do you want to use reflection to instantiate an instance of an interface?

Comment: With what you are trying, I think if you do like `public class ObjectPool<T> where T : IRecyclable`; that would be just fine.

Comment: I am not convinced you really want the "new()" constraint here.  Creating a new `ObjectPool<ISomeInterface>` does not require the new constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interfaces can only implement other interfaces.

```
interface IA : IB, IC
{
    ...
}
```

A good way to solve your dilemma is to introduce a factory interface as well.

```
interface IThing
{
    ...
}

interface IThingFactory
{
    IThing Create();
}
```

Now anything that wants to have the ability to create things should receive an `IThingFactory` for that purpose.

If you need a generic concept of a factory, you could use something like this:

```
interface IFactory<T>
{
    T Create();
}

class ObjectPool<T, F>
    where T : IRecyclable        
    where F : IFactory<T>
{
    public ObjectPool(F factory)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't provide an interface there. `class` and `new` require it to be a constructable reference type.

Comment: But Daniel, this is valid right? `public class ObjectPool<T> where T : IRecyclable`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot construct an `ObjectPool<ISomeInterface>`.  You could have a generic type `MyClass<TT> where T:class,ISomeInterface,new()` declare an `ObjectPool<TT>` within it, and then later on declare variables of type `MyClass<SomeClassWhichImplementsISomeInterfaceAndHasADefaultConstructor>`, but the compiler can only execute methods for `ObjectPool<T>` when `T` is of a *particular known class type* which meets all the constraints.

Alternatively, you could omit the `new` constraint and then require that any code which constructs an `ObjectPool<T>` must pass the constructor (or other method that creates the instance) a `Func<T>`.  That would make it possible to create an `ObjectPool<ISomeInterface>` provided that one had a method which, when called, would return a new object of some suitable type that implemented `ISomeInterface`.